# High performance query to count many to many data

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

**Requests Table:**

```
requests
    +id (INT) AUTO_INCREMENT
    +title (VARCHAR)
```

**Statuses Table:**

```
statuses
    +id (INT) AUTO_INCREMENT
    +title (VARCHAR)
```

**Relationship Table:**

```
request_status (MANY TO MANY)
    +id (INT) AUTO_INCREMENT
    +request_id (INT) Foreign Key
    +status_id (INT)
```

I want to count only those requests whose current **status_id is 2**. Current Request's Status (status_id) is the last one in the request_status table.

What will be the perfect high-performance query if data is around 1600k

Comment: Can you please make the question very easy to understand? With sample input and ouput?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why do you think that something is not performing properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the latest status is the one with greatest id:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM request_status
WHERE status_id = 2
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM request_status AS x
    WHERE request_id = request_status.request_id
    AND id > request_status.id
)
```

Or this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT 1
    FROM request_status
    GROUP BY request_id
    HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN status_id = 2 THEN id END) = MAX(id)
) AS x
```

You will need some indexes. I suggest creating these ones:

```
KEY ix1 (request_id, status_id)
KEY ix2 (status_id,  request_id)
```

Comment: (While you are at it, get rid if `id` and make one of those KEYs the PK.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM request_status WHERE status_id = 2;
```

should work best if I understood your question correctly - which would be to count the pairs in which status_id equals 2.

Comment: (Now finish your Answer by providing the optimal index.)

Answer (score 0):

The schema for the relation table has several inefficiencies.  I discuss them [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

But, instead, lets change the schema to make it even more efficient.  Instead of 3 tables with a many:many mapping, have just one table:

```
CREATE TABLE requests (
    id ...,
    latest_status  ENUM('eating', 'sleeping', 'running'),
    all_statuses    SET('eating', 'sleeping', 'running'),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

(Alternatively, you could use `TINYINTs`, but with different syntax.)

When the status for a given `request` changes, set `latest_status` and "or" the new status into `all_statuses`.

To check for latest being `running`:  `WHERE latest_status = 'running'`.

Or, if using some numeric value:   `WHERE latest_status = 2`.